# Background color not showing up

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I'm just trying to change the background of my page. The gradient pops up, but the full opaque gradient is not showing after adding a className to my div. Here is my 'Navbar.jsx':

```
    'use client';

    import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

    import styles from '../styles';
    import { navVariants } from '../utils/motion';

    const Navbar = () => (
      <motion.nav
        variants={navVariants}
        initial="hidden"
        whileInView="show"
        className={`${styles.xPaddings} py-8 relative`}
      >
        <div className='absolute w-[50%] inset-0 gradient-01' />
      </motion.nav>
    );

    export default Navbar;
```

This is my 'page.js':

```
    import { Footer, Navbar } from '../components';
    import { About, Explore, Feedback, GetStarted, Hero, Insights, WhatsNew, World } from '../sections';

    const Page = () => (
      <div className='bg-primary-black overflow-hidden'>
        <Navbar />
        <Hero />
        <About />
        <Explore />
        <GetStarted />
        <WhatsNew />
        <World />
        <Insights />
        <Feedback />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );

    export default Page;
```

I've gone over the code a few times and haven't found any errors, but I am a beginner, so there is definitely something I could have missed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have confused `CSS` and Module `CSS`. Regular `CSS` behave the same in `JSX` as it is in `HTML`.

Assume your `CSS` are correct, it is best to rewrite to the below codes:

```
// ...other imports

// Or even shorter, "import '../styles.css'".
import styles from '../styles.css';


const Navbar = () => (
    {/* rewrite the below className for `motion.nav`. */}
    <motion.nav
        variants={navVariants}
        initial="hidden"
        whileInView="show"
        className="xPaddings py-8 relative"
    >
        <div className='absolute w-[50%] inset-0 gradient-01' />
    </motion.nav>
);

export default Navbar;
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: I just started the server again and it worked, but thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @Rob That is strange, but it's great that your code works. Happy coding!